# VueJs: How to paginate an array items with a load more button

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

I have an array of objectsand I want to show only 3 at a time with a button that when clicked,show 3 more, making 6 in total and so on.

This is what I have currently:

```html
// vue template
<ul>
  <li v-for="(order, index) in orders" :key="index">
    {{order.item_description}}
  </li>
</ul>
<button @click="loadMore">load more </button>
```

For the script, I have the data and some computed properties:

```js
data() {
  return {
    orders: [
      {
        id: 1,
        item_description: "One",
        created_at: "23, Dec 2019",
        delivery_address: "Location",
        cost: "2500"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        item_description: "Two",
        created_at: "23, Dec 2019",
        delivery_address: "Location",
        cost: "2500"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        item_description: "Three",
        created_at: "23, Dec 2019",
        delivery_address: "Location",
        cost: "2500"
      }
      // .... upto 12 items
    ],
    currentPage: 1,
    maxPerPage: 3
  }
},
computed: {
  totalResults() {
    return Object.keys(this.orders).length
  },
  pageCount() {
    return Math.ceil(this.totalResults / this.maxPerPage)
  },
  pageOffest() {
    return this.maxPerPage * this.currentPage
  }
},
methods: {
  loadMore() {
    this.currentPage += 1
  }
}
}
```

My confusion is how to get the `orders` to be paginated using the `maxPerPage` and then add more using the `loadMore`

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-dirac-vxleo) for demo

Comment: Your codesandbox seems broken, can you fix it ?

Comment: @ZecKa I have fixed it :)

Comment: do you load more items with an api?

Comment: @Ifaruki No, I'm loading more from the orders array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add computed property like:

```js
paginatedOrders() {
   return this.orders.slice(0, this.currentPage * this.maxPerPage);
}
```

And then make your loop with this property:

```js
<li v-for="(order, index) in paginatedOrders" :key="index">{{order.item_description}}</li>
```

additonnaly you can hide read more button if you already display all items

```js
<button @click="loadMore" v-if="currentPage * maxPerPage < orders.length">load more</button>
```

Check it on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-voice-jo3gn?file=/src/App.vue)

*Note: Keep in mind that the most common use of the "load more" button is to load other items with an api call or ajax request. This only works if you load all your orders beforehand*.

Comment: If this doesn't work update `in paginatedOrders` to `in paginatedOrders()`

Comment: @B3none you probably add paginatedOrders in methods instead of computed

Comment: you're right! I was using the composition API